# Does x-Cart strips tags from posted data?

Tags: php, post, x-cart

I send data from form, where the textarea contains html tags. On PHP side I do not see them, using:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $_POST );
echo "</pre>";
exit();
```

I get:

[image]

Where have paragraph tags gone?

In source code they are clearly gone:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [mode] => save_product
    [id] => 1
    [title] => Banana Shake
    [categoryid] => 1
    [serving] => 34.50
    [orderby] => 10
    [intro] => Intro
    [instructions] => Empty contents of packet into a shaker or blender, add 200-240ml of cold water and shake/mix until fully dissolved.
Consume within 10 minutes for full nutritional benefit.
...</pre>
```

**EDIT**

I am using x-Cart's engine to manipulate data, could be the x-Cart strips those tags.

Comment: Are you using a framework? It might strip post data out of the box...please give more details

Comment: You're displaying this *in the browser*, right? A browser which *interprets HTML tags*, right?!

Comment: No framework, pure HTML post form to PHP page.

Comment: @ka_lin `<pre>` does not turn off HTML interpretation.

Comment: Try this `echo htmlentities($_POST['instructions']);` and see if the tags show there

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but that's not what `<pre>` does.

Comment: @skobaljic save it in database and check once

Comment: @ka_lin http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a1876071b75e50f1df57e1f281d8d338a4b5e68 – This demonstration doesn't work within this sandbox.

Comment: @ka_lin **Exactly**, because that sandbox HTML-escapes all output. Your demonstration is inconclusive.

Comment: @skobaljic To answer your question: no, PHP does not strip anything from anything automagically. Your example is not reproducible on stock PHP installations.

Comment: I thought you said *"No framework"*?!

Comment: Please look at edit and x-cart's tag. Think x-cart strips my tags (I know it should work, that's why I asked the question).

Comment: Sorry, in this case I used x-cart's core only to simplify queries :(

Comment: Did you try `var_dump($_POST)` to see if the `tags` are there or not because `print_r()` might not just display the tags but `interprets them` where as `var_dump()` would `dump`out the contents of the `variable`. Perhaps it's there but not just displayed...

Comment: @Poiz Both `print_r` and `var_dump` won't modify the actual string content at all, just the surrounding meta data output is slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set trusted variables at beginning of the script this way:

```
define('USE_TRUSTED_POST_VARIABLES', 1);
$trusted_post_variables = array('intro', 'instructions');
```

That way x-cart won't strip any tags.

Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** this answer is written on the presumption that you are not using a framework or [other method that strips HTML tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) from your post.

Your paragraph tags are still there. Since you're printing them in the browser, the browser is interpreting them as real `<p>` tags. If you were to look at the page's source code, you'd see the tags. (Google "`<your browser name>` view page source" for instructions on how to do this.)

You could also use `htmlentities($_POST['instructions])` or `htmlspecialchars($_POST['instructions])` to change the HTML tags to entities, which will cause them to be printed to the browser.

- [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
- [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Comment: Thanks, but really a problem is with x-cart, need to know how to make it accept post data as is, cause I know it is possible (there are many fields in admin that use html).